# viewing 8bpp data from a rom in python using tkinter

Tags: python, bitmap, tkinter, rom

I am trying to view image data from a rom the images are in a **8bpp planar composite** format

i've been testing using for testing using **Super Mario All-Stars (USA)** using the **offset:257C00** (where the box art is).

I can view it on **tilemolester 0.16** and I got this (useing custom colour palette):
Super Mario All-Stars (box data)

[image]

I tried many times extracting the data using python but I had no idea how,
there's probably a easy way on doing this but I couldn't figure it out.

i know it looks realy bad but here: [code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q9b7ryfwtnrzhx0/8bpp%20test.py?dl=0)

Comment: can you show your coding attempts, and what went wrong?

Comment: i know it looks realy bad but here [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q9b7ryfwtnrzhx0/8bpp%20test.py?dl=0) 

(its based on a open source nes viewer) 
you will need the Super Mario All-Stars (USA) rom box data is at the offset: 88064. 

i'm not that sure what went wrong (probably everything) it looks like the data corrupted but it isn't, maybe the offset is wrong.

Comment: the output is this: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wx7dfjk8c84f525/f.png?dl=0)

Comment: anybody have any idea???